# Changing object detection code functional in tkinter GUI development

Tags: python, tkinter

I am running the Mobilenetv2-Yolov3 model for single object detection in the image and it detects my target object successfully. I am new to Tkinter and I need to change this line to be functional:

```
tkinter(!python3 main.py --mode=CROP \
  --input=""../T"" \
  --output="../I" \
  --anchors_path='model_data/yolo_anchors.txt' \
  --classes_path='model_data/cervix_classes.txt' \
  --model logs/mobilenetv2_2020-12-21/ep186-loss0.185-val_loss0.337.h5 &)
```

The GitHub repo I used was: https://github.com/fsx950223/mobilenetv2-yolov3,
may I look for argument parser?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Do you want to make a GUI wrapper around that library? It looks like it will take quite a bit of code to get that to work with `tkinter`.

Comment: I want to develop GUI, but I do have lots of arguments am not sure how to change this to work with tkinter like passing this command to button to display the result

Comment: Do you want to run the library in a new process, new thread or in the same thread?

Comment: if its possible I prefer in the same thread

Comment: As long as it doesn't take more than a few seconds to run it shouldn't cause a lot of issues. Do you know what function you are going to call? What parameters are you going to pass in? If you don't, your only option is a new process. The problem is that this is the first time I have seen that library so I have no idea how it works.

Comment: I know the function and parameters since it works well what  want but to develop GUI I 
need to change the code right and am confused to do that because here the functions are in main.py file. I am working in googl colab

Comment: Have you installed that library using `pip` or something similar? If so you should be able to just use `from <library name> import main` then `main.main(...)` for example.

Comment: It is a phyton script as in github repo provided in question

Comment: first you have to learn `tkinter` and how works `GUI`s because this will need a lot of changes. And if you run it on Google Colab then `tkinter` will be useless because `tkinter` displays on monitor directly connected to computer - and when you run it on Google Colab server then will try to display on monitor connected to server - but server doesn't have monitor and you can't even see it. Server doesn't even have XWindows needed to display any GUI.